# how to insert the activeTab permission

Tags: javascript

how can i use  activeTab permission

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "dailyVideoStream",
"options_ui": {
  "page": "html/OptionsSite/OptionsSite.html"
},
"permissions": [ "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", 
"\u003Call_urls>", "tabs", "unlimitedStorage", "webNavigation", "downloads", 
"proxy" ],
"short_name": "DVideo",
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"version": "1.0.1",
"web_accessible_resources": [ "html/VidPlaySite/VidPlaySite.html", 
"html/VideoPopup/VideoPopup.html", "html/VideoPopup/VideoPopup.css", 
"html/LibrarySite/librarySite.html" ]
}
```

how to insert the activeTab permission without getting alert

Comment: Please go through the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab

Comment: I did , but still getting the warning message , any suggestion ?